Computing the root of a polynomial that has the lowest imaginary part
Suppose that we have a polynomial $P$ of degree $n$ whose roots are known to be all complex and with distinct imaginary parts.
With such conditions, $P$  should have a unique root $z_0$ such as
$|\Im(z0)| = min_{P(z)=0} |\Im(z)| > 0$ where $\Im(z)$ is the imaginary part of $z$.
Question:
Is there a method to numerically compute only this specific root that has the lowest imaginary part among all the roots of $P$ ?

What’s the context for this? Largest magnitude is easy  (http://www.numdam.org/article/M2AN_1990__24_6_693_0.pdf), and that can be manipulated into largest imaginary part, but smallest magnitude imaginary part seems trickier. Roots with very small imaginary roots of $f$ are probably near minima of $|f|$ on real line, though finding all the real roots of $|f|’$ is probably not that much faster than finding the actual roots of $f$.

@Eric, you wrote that "Roots with very small imaginary roots of f
are probably near minima of |f|
on real line". Why would it be the case ?

Well, in the extreme, real roots are minima of $ |f(z)|$. In another extreme, the minima of $|z-z_0|$ on the real line is the real part of $z_0$. If you think about $log|f(x)|$, you get $\sum_i log |x-z_i|$ and for all of those zeroes not near $x$, that’s approximately constant near $x$, so in the neighborhood of a zero $z_0$ that’s far from other roots and near the real line, it’ll act just like that term which has a nearby minima.

In fact, if $f(z)$ of degree $n$ has a root at $ai$ and all other roots have magnitude more than $2na$, then you can compute $|f(x)|’(a)>0>|f(x)|’(-a)$, so there is a local minima between $-a$ and $a$.
